# how to login on SSO/OIDC using cypress

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, openid-connect, cypress, google-authentication

I am trying to login on our office portal for which OIDC is configured which uses OAuth 2.0 Client ID using the google account. So I am trying to automate this website for which OIDC is configured using Cypress but getting the below error:
[Cypress output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnmKB.png)

```
describe( `Test Scenarios`, () => {

it.only('Login with valid credentials', function () {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('URL'));
    cy.url().should('contain', "accounts.google.com");
    cy.get("input[type='email']").click({
        force: true
     });
    cy.get("input[type='email']").clear().type(this.data.email);
    cy.wait(20000);
});
```

Is there some other way to automate OIDC/SSO configured website using Cypress? I am new to Cypress and SSO.

Also, tried to refer to this link [cypress-social-logins](https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins) but couldn't find anything so not sure if I am on the right path.

Comment: Well, it's not an easy task, to be honest. Here are a couple of articles I've found: https://medium.com/tenets/cypress-identityserver4-cracking-the-oidc-protocol-6da42289731f   and https://auth0.com/blog/end-to-end-testing-with-cypress-and-auth0/

Comment: @soeik Thank you for the reference links. I will try and let's hope it works out.